# What is this round, shiny black bug, about 10mm long, found in Singapore?

Tags: bug-identification, singapore

I found this insect under my shirt while working, it is the first time I ever see something like that and it is kind of too small for me to tell what it is.

[image]
[image]

I do not have a property measuring tool to get it's size but it is at most 1cm across. Had too zoom a lot with my phone camera to take these pictures so it is kind of blur.

If it matters I live in Singapore, there are various trees around the place but I did not go into any patches of dense forested areas.

Comment: Is it all black or more of a brown color, any other identifying marks or colors? Does it appear perfectly round?

Comment: Welcome Ben! That's a cool bug! I have a few questions in addition to  Nate Wengert's. Is it shiny? It looks like it, unless that's just the picture. Does the head seem like a whole different section, like a beetle, or is the whole bug one piece and the head just peeks out from under the big shell?  In the bottom picture (shell side up), which end has the head underneath? Was it alive when you found it?  Did it bite you? It's interesting that you've never seen one at all before. I look forward to hearing more about it, so we can try and figure it out!

Comment: @NateW it looks black visually, though in the images I took there is some brown on the legs

Comment: @Sue  yes, it is shiny. Not just camera result, it does reflect light. I can't say much about the head. I inspect it via the images I uploaded it is really less than 2cm in length. In the first image the head is on the right side. It is under the shell, not sure if it can extend it out. It is alive but it crawls very slowly, covers about 5 cm in 29 seconds. It did not bite me even when I placed it on my finger.

Comment: @NateW it appears round but on closer inspection it is slightly longer than wide.

Comment: Looks like a type of clown beetle.

Comment: Ben, I found a Singapore bug that looks like it. I don't know for sure, though. This is a Google search page for ["shiny black round bug in Singapore."](https://www.google.com/search?q=shining+flower+beetle&client=firefox-b-1-ab&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi81a_RiO_ZAhUPvVMKHd_nDccQ7AkIQQ&biw=1138&bih=538) (The search should have been easy, but it took about 10 different tries before these specific bugs came up!) The one that looks the most like it to me is actually called ["Shining Flower Beetle (Phalacridae)"](https://bugguide.net/node/view/196653/bgimage). Your thoughts?

Comment: @Sue Very close, but the one I found is more circular while the Phalacridae is described to be very oval. The legs are shorter and the head segment is almost not visible but the Phalacridae have observable legs and head - though that might be due to the higher quality photos available. Might be one of the subspecies

Comment: It is also much larger than the described 1.5-2mm, the one I found is almost 10mm.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong identification, and definitely sorry about the size. I'm in one of the last few countries that still uses the imperial system of measurements! I should have used my converter!

Answer (score 8):

Based on the poor-quality of the photos (and my limited knowledge of Singapore insects) it would be very difficult to definitively ID this to species.

However, based on the shape and size, you're very likely looking at a species of **ladybird beetle** (aka ladybug; family [Coccinellidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coccinellidae)).

Specifically, I think this is a member of the subfamily [Chilocorinae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilocorinae).

> They are shiny color and usually have no spots or patterns on their wing covers. Their bodies are in round helmet shapes.

To show you an example species from this subfamily, here is a picture of [*Chilocorus nigrita*](http://keys.lucidcentral.org/keys/phoenix/ChilocorusSpeciesOfIndia/Chilocorus%20key/html/chilocorus_nigrita.htm):

[image]

<sup>Source: [www.NatureLoveYou.sg](http://www.natureloveyou.sg/Minibeast-Beetle/Chilocorus%20nigrita/Main.html)</sup>

**Formal Description:**

> Length 3.2-4.0 mm; width 2.9-3.9 mm.... Elytra black, shiny, with fine punctations. Ventral side including legs and inner margins of elytral epipleura orange yellow to yellowish brown, outer margins of epipleura pitchy brown to black  [[Source](http://keys.lucidcentral.org/keys/phoenix/ChilocorusSpeciesOfIndia/Chilocorus%20key/html/chilocorus_nigrita.htm)].

**Range**

[This site](http://keys.lucidcentral.org/keys/phoenix/ChilocorusSpeciesOfIndia/Chilocorus%20key/html/chilocorus_nigrita.htm) suggests that this specific species is common in India but also found in Malaysia, but the image above was actually taken in Singapore.

You can try to narrow to a specific species via [Booth (2009)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/bulletin-of-entomological-research/article/review-of-the-species-resembling-chilocorus-nigrita-coleoptera-coccinellidae-potential-agents-for-biological-control/39D9C7D7391A537ECFFA15F4F2D5A4F5) or the ID key found [here](http://keys.lucidcentral.org/keys/phoenix/ChilocorusSpeciesOfIndia/Chilocorus%20key/html/chilocorus_nigrita.htm).

---

<sup>Booth, R.G., 1998. A review of the species resembling Chilocorus nigrita (Coleoptera: Coccinellidae): potential agents for biological control. Bulletin of entomological research, 88(4), pp.361-367.</sup>